# How to unbind volume from docker image?

Tags: docker

I created an image from a running container, which had a volume mapped at the time, e.g.: `-v /home/user/myproject/xyz:/opt/xyz`. Now, when I run that image, e.g.: `docker run -i -t myimage bash`, there is a mount in /opt/xyz. There isn't any files in it, but I cannot delete or unmount that folder.

Anyone knows how to get rid of that binding?..

**UPDATE**: one method I found is to start a container, export it, then import it back as a new image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently supported. I would do one of two things:

- Ignore the directory. If there aren't any files in it then it shouldn't be making any difference.
- Create the image again, using a `Dockerfile` - this is **best practice**.

Comment: OK, it's not that difficult to create the image again with my `Dockerfile`. I thought it will take lots of time but it didn't. Thanks for your advice.